# How to create a table view with only one row selectable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi need to create a table view with only one cell selectable like this img.

[image]

Comment: What have you done to achieve this?

Comment: this is a screenshot of calendar app

Comment: Do you know how to create a regular table view?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Sound Effects";
return cell;
```

}

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

     if(path.row == 0)
     {
         if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         } else {
             cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: this should work for only first row.. if you want that it should work for all the rows then remove  if(path.row == 0) conditions for both the methods..

Answer (score 0):

if you like only one row selectable you have to manage this in the methods of the table:

1. in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
    you need to implement the selection logic. if you click on a non-selected object, you select it and deselect all others, or only the one that is currently selected (if there is one selected). If you click on a selected object, just deselect it here
2. dont forget to do `[theTableView reloadData];`
    in case your screen does not update if you change something in the table's content
3. then to redraw you just ensure that your method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
    ensures that the object which is selected is marked somehow. This way you can also do nice things like showing a toggle ON/OFF button or anything you may whish.